# Full Screen Video Crashing

Tags: imac

For the past few weeks my iMac has been crashing when I watch any Flash or Silverlight video in full screen. I have looked at the console and have not been able to figure out the issue. When it occurs my computer restarts and I get an error with the below info:

```
Anonymous UUID:       AEF04628-8054-14A1-4974-86A69C32865D

Wed Jul  9 17:12:00 2014
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8005edc24e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8005ea50dc, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff80d4548018, CR3: 0x000000003b121000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0xffffff80d4548010, RBX: 0xffffff800f5e0f58, RCX: 0xffffff8011064f68, RDX: 0xffffff8018cdda10
RSP: 0xffffff8111823c40, RBP: 0xffffff8111823c60, RSI: 0x000000002b99cde0, RDI: 0xffffff8018cdda20
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x00000000cccccccd, R10: 0xffffff80064d1600, R11: 0x0000000000000111
R12: 0xffffff8018cdd800, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8018cdda20, R15: 0x0000000000000200
RFL: 0x0000000000010287, RIP: 0xffffff8005ea50dc, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80d4548018, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81118238d0 : 0xffffff8005e22f79 
0xffffff8111823950 : 0xffffff8005edc24e 
0xffffff8111823b20 : 0xffffff8005ef3746 
0xffffff8111823b40 : 0xffffff8005ea50dc 
0xffffff8111823c60 : 0xffffff8005e902e8 
0xffffff8111823d10 : 0xffffff8005e95c33 
0xffffff8111823d40 : 0xffffff8005e8f39d 
0xffffff8111823d70 : 0xffffff8005e8e5ec 
0xffffff8111823db0 : 0xffffff8005e7e58c 
0xffffff8111823ec0 : 0xffffff8005e825cf 
0xffffff8111823ef0 : 0xffffff8005e1d147 
0xffffff8111823f20 : 0xffffff8005ec9a4d 
0xffffff8111823fb0 : 0xffffff8005ef3d18 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
13E28

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BBFADD17-672B-35A2-9B7F-E4B12213E4B8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005e00000
System model name: iMac11,3 (Mac-F2238BAE)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 24126521203634
last loaded kext at 23471806422303: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104 (addr 0xffffff7f884ff000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 23570895892111: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7f884ff000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.logmein.driver.LogMeInSoundDriver   1.0.3
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.28
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.2.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.6f1
com.apple.kext.AMD5000Controller    1.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.6f1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.2.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: iMac11,3, BootROM IM112.0057.B01, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.93 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.59f2
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5750, ATI Radeon HD 5750, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.6f1 14216, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD1001FALS-40Y6A0, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: MFC-J6510DW
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the OS and Silverlight and Flash, and restart your iMac.

After the restart you can reset the PRAM.